# How to render an HTML web page in video on android?

Tags: java, android, html, html-rendering

I am working on an idea where I need to render an HTML5  web page in video on android. Actually it works this way that a video is being displayed on the screen of the TV and I want to render a  web page on that video So far my research shows that this is called as video overlay or composite which can be found here [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing). My question is how can I acheive this in Android??

Or in other words I would say how can I achieve video overlay in android. Is there  any API for that ??
 Any suggestion to achieve this will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance